Subir archivo a servidor por ajax en php
estoy intentando subir un archivo por medio de file, enviando el formulario por medio de ajax hacía el servidor mi código es el siguiente en html


<form id="ImgForm" name="ImgForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
     <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" />
     <input type="text" name="texto" />
     <button type="button" name="subirArchivo" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
            onclick="subirArchivoImg()">Subir Archivo</button>
 </form>



JS:


function subirArchivoImg() {
// console.log($("#ImgForm").serialize());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'subirArchivoImg.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#ImgForm").serialize(),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#probando').html(data);
        }
    })
}



Y mi php en el controlador tengo esto :
        if (isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']) && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            echo 'aosdbaisbd';
            $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']; //nombre y ubicacion que tiene el archivo localmente
            $fileName = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']; //Nombre del archivo
            $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['size']; //Tamaño del archivo
            $fileType = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['type']; //Tipo de archivo
            $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName); //quitamos los puntos y separamos en arreglo
            $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps)); //vemos que extension tiene tomando lo que está después del ultimo punto

           

                $uploadFileDir = '../archivos/'; //definimos la ubicacion donde se guardará el archivo
                $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $fileName; //concatenamos para darle el nombre y ubicacion con el que se guardará

               move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path))

                    

El input de nombre texto si llega hasta el controlador, ya que me muestra el texto en pantalla, sólo el archivo no lo puedo mostrar ni guardar

Logré solucionarlo con un artículo que encontré en la web
Hice un form más sencillo:


<form>
   <p><input type="file" name="file" class="file" required></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>



el JS lo modifique totalmente por esto:


$(function () {
    $('input[name="submitFoto"]').on('click', function () {
        var file_data = $('.file').prop('files')[0];
        if (file_data != undefined) {
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'subirArchivoImg.php',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 'success') {
                        alert('File uploaded successfully.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
                    }

                    $('.file').val('');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});



Ya el PHP lo dejé solamente con estas líneas en el controlador, el cual llamo desde el subirarchivo.php
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], './fotos/'. $_FILES['file']['name']);
          
        echo "success";
        die();


el motivo del porque no lo visualizas es que no estas usando FormData, te dejo este código para que lo adecues al tuyo.
var file_data = $('#archivoDatosElim')[0].files[0]; //tu input
var data = new FormData(); // Creas el formdata
data.append("archivo", file_data); // insertas la info en la variable

$.ajax({  
 data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
});// data en peticion ajax

$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']; // lees la info en php


Buenas, para tu respuesta deberías mejorar. Lo ideal es que formes el fragmento completo de la respuesta, con todo lo necesario, no solo des fragmentos de código suelto, que a ojo del curioso, no funcionará. Una vez hayas editado mejor la respuesta, revotaré la respuesta.

ya lo resolvió así que no importa, el caso es que pudo hacerlo ;), fomento mas el ser autodidacta, mas no resolverles todo ;)

No es que resuelvas todo el tema, es que para otro que venga a leer tu respuesta, simplemente, es un desorden de código.
